# Spring Boot/ Hibernate: Is there anything wrong with Fetching lazy children using @PostLoad

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

So i have a parent object that has 2 children that are collections.

However one of those children will be null.

There is a variable type in my Parent object, if it is "x" then the children collection of type  "y" will be null, if type is "y" then children collection of type" x" will be null.

Whenever I retrieve the parent, I always need the children too.

Is there anything inherently wrong with doing something like this in the Entity

```
  @PostLoad
  public void fetchCollections(){
if(type == Y){
// fetch Collection<X> by doing collection.getSize();
}
    if(type == Y){
// fetch Collection<Y> by doing collection.getSize();
}
```

Comment: This looks hacky to me. You probably want to look into entity graphs: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-entity-graph

Comment: It seems like you want to initialise the lazy relationships dynamically. Have a look at the JPA Criteria API to write your custom database queries. Then, entity graphs are one option. The other one is also the fetch join of Hibernate.